# On hover image display div right next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Any help would be appreciated! As of now I have the following...when you hover over the image on the left the div shows up right next to it and toggles left/right. However, I need four on my page, when I hover over one the rest do the same how can I separate them? Or is there a better method...ie. Show/hide function...how would I go about this using Jquery? I've searched several places and none display what I need. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slide-toggle").hover(function(){
    $(".box").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    }); 
  });
 });
```

```css
.slide-toggle {
  float:left;
}
.box{
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
}
.box-inner{
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
  padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason this is happening is because `$(".box").animate()` will animate **EVERY** element with the class name "box". Similarly, `$(".slide-toggle").hover()` will add this action to **EVERY** element with the class name "slide-toggle". **So every time you hover over any 'slide-toggle', every 'box' will animate.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.next()` with `".box"` as parameter

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slide-toggle").hover(function() {
    $(this).next(".box").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-toggle {
  float: left;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
}
.box-inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
</div>
<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the div with class `.box` right next to the image with the `next()` function  like

```
$(this).next('.box').animate({
      width: "toggle"
    });
```

It doesn't work in your case because when you use

```
$(".box").animate({
  width: "toggle"
});
```

It will select all the html elements that have a class `.box` and then apply animation on all of them

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slide-toggle").hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.box').animate({
      width: "toggle"
    }); 
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-toggle {
  float:left;
}
.box {
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
}
.box-inner {
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
  padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your box is the sibling of image tag. You can wrap image and box in another parent tag and than make reference from image tag to parent and find box and animate that. But you can directly find next box to image by following code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slide-toggle").hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.box').animate({
      width: "toggle"
    }); 
  });
 });
```

it will work fine. Vote up it works

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need JavaScript or jQuery to do this. You can do it in pure CSS:

```
.slide-toggle {
  float:left;
}
.box {
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
}
.box-inner {
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.slide-toggle:hover + .box {
  /* use an animation or transition here to change the width */
}

<img class="slide-toggle" src="tree.png" width="50" height="50">
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
</div>
```